# TailwindCSS: How to add elements from the right side in a grid?

Tags: grid, tailwind-css, right-align

Given the classnames "grid grid-cols-5 gap-2 place-items-end"

I get:
[image: items aligned on the left]

Wanted:
[image: items aligned on the right]

Is there a CSS-only way of resolving this ? Having to set a "col-span-4" on the 6h star from js is a bit tedious (considering the number of stars I can get is unknown).

Comment: `direction: rtl;` can be a possible way to achieve it. https://play.tailwindcss.com/lVJN7npilZ

Comment: lovely. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it, thanks a lot for sharing this trick!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reversing the second row with `direction: rtl;` will do the job.

HTML:

```
<div class="rtl-grid container w-96 bg-red-700 h-auto grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 p-4 -mt-4">
  <div class="bg-white h-12"></div>
  <div class="bg-white h-12"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rtl-grid {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lVJN7npilZ)